# Android. Navigation View

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer, android-navigation-view

Как убирать отступы между названиями Feed \ Interests итд, а то мучаюсь уже второй день и не могу найти решение. Можно по подробней объяснить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажите как вы создаете и добавляете элементы меню.

Comment: зависит от того, как сделано ваше меню.

Comment: @metalurgus я его делаю по стандарту создавая в папке /menu список item'ов и импортируя в NavigationView через 'app:menu="@menu/drawer"', но я уже понял как изменить стандартную разметку NavigationView

Comment: @metalurgus щас распишу свое решение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменение стандартной разметки NavigationView.

Для начала создаем стиль для нашего **NavigationView** в файле   ***/res/values/styles.xml***

```
<style name="NavDrawerTextStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item> <!-- Размер текста -->
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/action_navigation_item_text_bg_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/action_navigation_item_text_color</item>
</style>  <!-- Если chaked = true, то цвет текста оранжевый -->

<style name="NavigationViewStyle">
    <item name="android:paddingTop">2dp</item> 
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">40dp</item><!-- menu item height-->
    <item name="listPreferredItemHeightSmall">40dp</item><!-- menu item height-->
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemPaddingLeft">16dp</item>
    <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingLeft">16dp</item>
</style>
```

В стиле ***NavDrawerTextStyle*** мы описываем стиль текста, который будет отображаться в нашем меню.

В стиле  ***NavigationViewStyle*** мы описываем уже сами отступы. В самом NavigationView стоит все по **default**.

> android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall

*Отвечает за высоту item, т.е. Feed, Interests и всё то, что находится в моем меню.*

> android:listPreferredItemPaddingLeft

*Отвечает за отступ слева.*

В файле ***/res/values/dimens*** просто добавьте эту строчку.

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_icon_padding" tools:override="true">16dp</dimen>
```

Меняет расстояние справа от иконки, т.е. расстояние между иконкой и текстом.

В конечном итоге, получится вот такой NavigationView, но без шапки.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_below="@+id/drawer_viewpager"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"
        app:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyle"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavDrawerTextStyle"/>
```

Иконку я добавляю программно.

```
navigationMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_item_feed).setChecked(true);
navigationMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_item_feed).setIcon(R.drawable.happ_drawer_icon);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]